# How to insert html block in @page Razor

Tags: c#, .net, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

Is it possible to insert html block in @page Razor page in the new ASP.NET core?

I want to insert html block the way I'm doing it in Angular - like when you insert components. Here's the problem: only in the Layout page the IntelliSense allows me to use @RenderSection

Also, the @RenderPage is not recognizable in the IntelliSense. 
If I'm using the @RenderPage it also gives error

So is it possible / is there a way to use the @RenderPage or to insert html blocks within .cshtml files with Razor?

Thanks

Comment: You can add any valid HTML blocks to your razor code. Ultimately all code in razor will be rendered as HTML to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `@Html.Partial()` method. You can provide it with a Partial View and Model for that view.

Example:

```
@Html.Partial("_NavBar")
```

or

```
@Html.Partial("_NavBar, Model.Customer")
```

Comment: I am not using ASP.MVC and when I try to use @Html it is not being recognized (I am using Razor, just not from ASP.NET application). What do I need to do to let it work?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to render another view into a view, the method that you need is 
`@Html.Partial("partialViewName")`.

This allow you to send a Model and other parameters.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure - is it part of the new Razor @page pages? or part of MVC? Because I'm building the website using only the Razor (don't want to use the MVC as it simple website).

Comment: Also, does @RenderPage is no longer part of the syntax?